# How did Adriel strike against the Order of the Cruciform Sword?

Tags: warrior-nun

Near the beginning of the second season of *Warrior Nun*, Adriel seemingly executes a rapid strike against the order of the Cruciform Sword that manages to take out virtually all their bases across the world, with relatively few survivors, with the details of the strike not being shown.

The show seems to hint that the divinium cross that one of the older nuns planted in Camilla might have been involved, perhaps allowing Adriel to control the nuns and make them kill themselves. However, Adriel was unable to take control of Camilla through the connection, or even influence her a little, and seemingly only was able to play mind games with her. Unless Camilla had an unusual resistance to control, it seems as if the cross did *not* necessarily allow control, and only allowed Adriel to try to tempt people to his side. Further, he would only have had a few months to put divinium crosses in the nuns in all the OCS bases across the world.

On the other hand, to judge from the talents displayed by his band of untrained, sometimes demon-possessed acolytes, they would have had quite a hard time defeating highly trained warrior nuns, let alone without leaving a trace.

As such, how did Adriel manage to kill nearly all the members of the OCS at their bases across the world simultaneously?

Comment: Much like anything else. He had some nuns possessed - they were his plants like the one who bugged Camilla. If you have insiders, it's easy to get defences turned off, gates open, and then good strike teams with machine guns...

Comment: @Mithoron - His "strike teams" (which were never shown, so we don't know if that is what happened or something else) would have been fanatics who had barely been training for months at best, and we have seen that one warrior nun is worth about five people with guns. If his fanatics could barely deal with a handful of nuns on his own turf, I find it difficult to think that they could take all of them out at once on theirs.

Comment: Well, even this one old nun could mow down these training younglings in the courtroom, with a single series from machine gun, so... If you have enough plants you can do pretty much anything. When this "conclave" or whatnot with Pope and his "trusted man" came I estimated A. had at least half a dozen of them turned and this was quite generous underestimate.

Comment: If anything, it makes me wonder how did he got so many people controlled. Well, these things are left mysterious for good reasons. If there was some big gloating about it, I doubt it would make the series better.

Comment: In general, the reason for all this was the good guys sat and did nothing while enemy prepared and hit them. This can be a plot hole, though.